# Eclipse Plugin Development Build Tool

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a Build Tool, that is able to build Eclipse Plugins with dependencies including OSGI and non-OSGI dependencies.

The Build Tool shall add .jars as well as other Eclipse Dependencies to the build path.

In general I want everything to just work as expected. I tried Maven with the Maven:Eclipse and with Tycho. Both do not work as I expect them to work (The cannot add .jars to my class path and make them available at runtime - only with dirty hacks).

Is there any Build tool out there?

Comment: What do you mean by "...shall add .jars as well as other Eclipse Dependencies to the build path"? To what build path? The plugin(s) you're trying to build?

Comment: @E-Riz Yes in a way it can be run from eclipse as Eclipse Application.

Comment: It's not clear what your looking for, then. Tycho *does* handle building including all dependencies from the target platform as well as specified in the plugin's manifest.

Comment: @E-Riz At least it should. I tried and it didn't work out as expected. Tycho was not able to resolve dependencies to another Java Project that is in our private MavenRepo (that is setup correct and works for other usecases). After three days of maven configuration nightmare I think Maven+EclipsePlugin is not something I want to persuade any longer. Without any build tool it works quite well. However, I think a BuildTool+Dependency managment should be used on the long term. That is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Tycho *is* the long-term solution, [it's used to build Eclipse packages](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366430) you get from the [Downloads page](https://eclipse.org/downloads/).

I suggest you post a question (or questions), either on here SO or [the tycho-users mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/tycho-user), about the specifics of the Tycho problems you encountered; it's not a trivial technology but there are knowledgeable people out there willing to help.

Comment: As already mentioned, I'd hoped for something else than tycho. But if tycho is the only solution, I have to reconsider on that topic. Thanks for sharing.